# How to disable cq OOTB bundle/component when it starts?

Tags: java, osgi, aem

We are migrate cq 6.0 to 6.1

We noticed that our functionality broken and It became work if to disable following component:

[image]

```
SocialJcrResourceProviderFactory
```

How can I disable it when cq starts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There used to be a bug in the Social resource provider that made search result appears twice when `ResourceResolver.findResources()` is used for searching. That's most likely the cause.

Please make sure the [latest hotfix](https://www.adobeaemcloud.com/content/marketplace/marketplaceProxy.html?packagePath=/content/companies/public/adobe/packages/cq610/social/hotfix/cq-socialcommunities-pkg) has been installed:

Also, check [other packages](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/aem61-available-hotfixes.html) that might have affected you.

Comment: **result appears twice** -  yes, it looks like our behaviour.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot download this hotfix. **There are no clouds available to install this package**

Comment: just open the last tab: ASSETS and there you can find a link to the zipped package

Comment: There written that **It is recommended to deploy the AEM 6.1 Communities FP1 feature pack**  I cannot find it. Can you please to find ?

Comment: it's probably: http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/deploy/communities.html#Latest%20Releases i.e. https://www.adobeaemcloud.com/content/marketplace/marketplaceProxy.html?packagePath=/content/companies/public/adobe/packages/cq610/social/featurepack/cq-socialcommunities-pkg but I suggest you talking to Adobe directly to get the answer from the first hand